# Remove 'BCDEdit set {bootmgr}' entry

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, bcdedit

While dual booting Ubuntu with windows, I had encountered 'Ubuntu grub not showing' problem.

At the stage, I typed on the following command on windows command prompt.

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

It did nothing but added corrupted `bootmgr` as default in my startup.
I have solved the problem another way. But the corrupted `bootmgr` also shows up in the grub.
How can I undo the change?
The grub looks like this:

[image: grub]

and boot manager looks like this:

[image: boot manager]